# Rxjs parallel subscribers

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5

I have the following code

```
x = new Rx.Subject()
z = new Rx.Subject()
loop = 900000000;

x
  .do(() => console.log('x start'))
  .do(() => { let i = loop; while(i--) continue })
  .subscribe(() => console.log('x end'))

z
  .do(() => console.log('z start'))
  .do(() => { let i = loop; while(i--) continue })
  .subscribe(() => console.log('z end'))

x.subscribe(z)
```

If I send a new event to `x`, this will be the output:

```
z start
z end
x start
x end
```

But I need the subscriptions to occur in parallel, and log it as

```
x start
z start
x end
z end
```

I don't mind about the order.

I've tried adding `.subscribeOn(Rx.Scheduler.async)` but the result is the same.

Check out an example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/FMlMO4OF8CSP1qz47Jyi?p=preview)

Comment: Congrats for finding one of the few use-cases I've seen for the scheduler parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you need `.observeOn()`

```
console.clear()
const x = new Rx.Subject();
const z = new Rx.Subject();
const loop = 900000000;

x
  .do(() => log('x start'))
  .do(() => { let i = loop; while(i--) continue })
  .observeOn(Rx.Scheduler.async)
  .subscribe(() => log('x end'));

z
  .do(() => log('z start'))
  .do(() => { let i = loop; while(i--) continue })
  .observeOn(Rx.Scheduler.async)
  .subscribe(() => log('z end'));

x.subscribe(z);

document
  .querySelector('#next')
  .addEventListener('click', () => x.next());

function log(data) {
  const logs = document.querySelector('#logs');
  const log = document.createElement('p');
  log.innerText = data;
  logs.appendChild(log);
}
```